# Math Books with Problems For Quantitative Trading

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, book-recommendation

I am looking a book or two that will teach me the fundamental math skills needed for quantitative / algorithmic trading.

Preferable criteria:

1. The book should contain problems which I am expected to solve
2. The book should be written as a tutorial, IE one that is designed to teach someone an area in which they may not be familiar
3. The book should provide a good fundamental introduction into the types of mathematics needed to be successful at quantitative / algorithmic trading
4. The book should be able to fill in any gaps if the reader only has a high school understanding of mathematics

You may suggest multiple books

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Articles

[Propietary Trading: Truth and Fiction](https://faculty.fuqua.duke.edu/~charvey/Teaching/BA453_2004/Muller_Proprietary_trading.pdf) by Peter Muller is a great introduction to prop trading.

[The Siren Song of Factor Timing](https://www.aqr.com/Insights/Research/Journal-Article/The-Siren-Song-of-Factor-Timing) by Cliff Asness is a good look into Smart Beta Timing.

[The Black and Scholes Model](http://bradley.bradley.edu/~arr/bsm/pg04.html) are notes by Kevin Rubash which do a good job covering Options Pricing.

[The High-Frequency Trading Arms Race](https://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/eric.budish/research/HFT-FrequentBatchAuctions.pdf) by E. Budish, P. Cramton, and J. Shim discuss High Frequency Trading pretty well.

## Books

[The Intelligent Investor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0060555661) by Benjamin Graham is a great overview of the entire field.

[When Genius Failed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0375758259) by   Roger Lowenstein summarizes the history of the field in a very relevant way.

[A Primer for the Mathematics of Financial Engineering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0979757622) by Dan Stefanica covers a lot of linear algebra and ODEs necessary in QF

[How I Became a Quant](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0096CHI7G) by Richard R. Lindsey and Barry Schachter is an excellent take on the skills you need to do well in the industry.